# import fresco: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rx.plugins.RxJavaPlugins

Tags: android, build.gradle, rx-java, fresco

In my android project ,I import fresco:

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
   compile('com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1') {
     exclude module: 'support-annotations'
   }
   compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1') {
     exclude module: 'support-annotations'
   }
   compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
   compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.3'
   compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
   compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.1'
   compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.3.1'

   compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.0.0'

}
```

when I run the project, it was wrong:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rx.plugins.RxJavaPlugins at rx.Observable.<clinit>(Observable.java:63) 
at com.xx.xx.MyService.initService(MyService.java:37) 
at com.xx.xx.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:99) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5293)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2154)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5049)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:818)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I do in MyServer

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe(){ 
  @Override public void call(Object o) {
       doSomeThing(); 
   } 
})
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.subscribe();
```

**supplement:**

in my SAMSUNG Galaxy S4 (GT-9500 ,Android 5.0.1) it is run well.
in Android 4.4 (MIUI 7 ,Android 4.4.4) ,it's wrong.

finally, forgive me poor English.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the latest Retrofit 1 version? `compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.3' means it's relatively old, 1.2.0 is the latest one.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos  Thank you for your answer.  I'm sorry, on holiday so didn't reply in time.    I  try to use the latest version   (compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.5'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1')  ,but it's still not working.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos  Before is for other reasons, now it's  run well,  thanks !

Comment: I didn't know how did this happen